# file_put_content() method error

Tags: php, mysql

I am putting some content into the file named 'index.php' and the code is below:

```
$put=<<<DEMO
<div id='container' style='width:100%'>
<style>
h1 {font-size:45px;}
</style>
<div id='header' style='background-color:#FFFFFF;'>
<h1 style='margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;height:20%;float:center;'>
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
```

line 108

```
<table align='left'><tr><td><img src="$row['Website_Name']/index.jpg" align='center' width='240' height='170'></td></tr></table>
 <table align='center'><br><tr><td><h1>$row['Business_Name']</td></tr></table>
 }

</h1></div>
</div>

DEMO;
file_put_contents("$str/index.php","$put");
```

But on running the code in the browser, I'm getting an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in E:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\registration.php on line 108
```

Comment: What is line 108, the html table string?

Comment: You get this error with the code in the file that is writing the code, or the code that has been written?

Comment: @axel.michel i used line 108 to notify the beginning of the line no. 108. I used it bcoz it is the line in which the error is

Comment: @user2078502 yes I get that, but in the code you pasted there are a few lines, starting with: <table.... ending with file_put_contents so which one is the real 108, in case it is the <table, there are quite a few problems, seems you mixing html and php.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your variable interpolation syntax. It's either

```
"$var[foo]"
```

or

```
"{$var['foo']}"
```

not

```
"$var['foo']"
```

Read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.